# how to implement the foldout animation view like the original iPhone google map app?

Tags: iphone

all coder , I see the foldout animation view in the original iPhone google map app,  I want the same effect in my view , but I have not find solution ...

how to do the same animation via iPhone sdk ? any tip will be much appreciated...

thanks...

iRobin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe that what you're looking for is `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlUp` and `UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown`, two transition effects that can be applied when switching views.  To produce the effect, you could use code like the following:

```
[UIView beginAnimations:nil context:nil];
[UIView setAnimationDuration:CURLANIMATIONDURATIONFORSWITCHINGVIEWS];
[UIView setAnimationTransition:UIViewAnimationTransitionCurlDown forView:self.view cache:YES];

[newlyVisibleController viewWillAppear:YES];
[previouslyVisibleController viewWillDisappear:YES];
[previouslyVisibleController.view removeFromSuperview];
[self.view addSubview:newlyVisibleController.view];
[previouslyVisibleController viewDidDisappear:YES];
[newlyVisibleController viewDidAppear:YES];

[UIView commitAnimations];
```

Comment: Thanks for your kindly help ! I will try this way .

Comment: seem this still can not be do the same effect .... official sdk does not public the related API yet .